# Getting javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure Error

Tags: java, ssl, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to send push notification to iPhone using Java-pns but I am getting the following error - 
**javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure**

My code is -

```
String token="95076d2846e8979b46efd1884206a590d99d0f3f6139d947635ac4186cdc5942";
String host = "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com";
int port = 2195;
String payload = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Message from Java o_O\"}}";

NotificationTest.verifyKeystore("res/myFile.p12", "password", false);
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
keyStore.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("res/myFile.p12"), "password".toCharArray());

KeyManagerFactory keyMgrFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
keyMgrFactory.init(keyStore, "password".toCharArray());

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(keyMgrFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port);
String[] cipherSuites = sslSocket.getSupportedCipherSuites();
sslSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(cipherSuites);
sslSocket.startHandshake();

char[] t = token.toCharArray();
byte[] b = Hex.decodeHex(t);

OutputStream outputstream = sslSocket.getOutputStream();

outputstream.write(0);
outputstream.write(0);
outputstream.write(32);
outputstream.write(b);
outputstream.write(0);
outputstream.write(payload.length());
outputstream.write(payload.getBytes());

outputstream.flush();
outputstream.close();

System.out.println("Message sent .... ");
```

For **NotificationTest.verifyKeystore**  I am getting that this valid is File and Keystore.

I am not understanding why I am getting this error.

Please anybody can help me?

Thanks in Advance ...

In my log I have seen that

** CertificateRequest

Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA

Cert Authorities:

[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 10

0000: 0D 00 00 06 03 01 02 40   00 00                    .......@..

** ServerHelloDone

[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4

0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....

** Certificate chain

**

** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1

[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 269

.

.

.

.

.

main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2

main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure

main, called closeSocket()

main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: 
handshake_failure

I am not understanding why **Cert Authorities:** is empty?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Impossible to answer without seeing a stack trace and possibly the output produced when running client or server with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake.` However:

> String[] cipherSuites = sslSocket.getSupportedCipherSuites();
>   sslSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(cipherSuites);

Don't do that. It is radically insecure, and it just conceals the real problem, which is almost always a certificate trust chain problem: either the client doesn't trust the server's certificate or vice versa.

Comment: thanks EJP for your reply. I am using cipherSuites = sslSocket.get...
Please suggest me what to use instead.

Comment: @DeepakPawar, usually, using the default cipher suites is fine. Don't set anything. In addition, you don't need to call `startHandshake` explicitly, it will be done when you start reading from the output stream.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, I will try with that