# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure Error in APN

Tags: java, ssl

I am trying to send push notification to iPhone using Java-pns but I am getting the following error...

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

This is my code...

```
String token="95076d2846e8979b46efd1884206a590d99d0f3f6139d947635ac4186cdc5942";

String host = "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com";
int port = 2195;
String payload = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Message from Java o_O\"}}";

NotificationTest.verifyKeystore("res/myFile.p12", "password", false);
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
keyStore.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("res/myFile.p12"), "password".toCharArray());

KeyManagerFactory keyMgrFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
keyMgrFactory.init(keyStore, "password".toCharArray());

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(keyMgrFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port);
String[] cipherSuites = sslSocket.getSupportedCipherSuites();
sslSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(cipherSuites);
sslSocket.startHandshake();

char[] t = token.toCharArray();
byte[] b = Hex.decodeHex(t);

OutputStream outputstream = sslSocket.getOutputStream();

outputstream.write(0);
outputstream.write(0);
outputstream.write(32);
outputstream.write(b);
outputstream.write(0);
outputstream.write(payload.length());
outputstream.write(payload.getBytes());

outputstream.flush();
outputstream.close();

System.out.println("Message sent .... ");
```

For `NotificationTest.verifyKeystore` I am getting that this valid is `File` and `Keystore`.

I am not understanding why I am getting this error.

This is my error log...

```
** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Cert Authorities:
<empty>
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes: len = 10
0000: 0D 00 00 06 03 01 02 40 00 00 .......@..
** ServerHelloDone
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes: len = 4
0000: 0E 00 00 00 ....
** Certificate chain
**
** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes: len = 269
...
main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT: fatal, handshake_failure
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

I am not understanding why Cert Authorities is empty?

Comment: As mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11050271/372643), don't enable all *supported* cipher suites. Some of them are supported by not enabled by default because they are insecure.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

To Send Push Notification to iPhone/ iPad I have used [**JavaPNS**](http://code.google.com/p/javapns/).

It is very easy to use and It worked for me.

We can simply follow [**This**](http://code.google.com/p/javapns/source/browse/wiki/How2UseJavapns.wiki) to use it.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend that you use keytool -list to compare the keystore on the client with those known to the server. The handshake error you are getting is because the Server has done it's hello and is expecting a Client Certificate in reply. You are not sending one. To fix this the PKCS12 certificate should be converted to PEM format (using openssl is one way) and then imported into a keystore using the keytool.

I suspect if you fix this by importing a client certificate into the keystore, then you will hit a second error. The second error will be about the empty CA certs - probably because you don't have a CA cert that is known to your server in your keystore. Import your CA and try again.

Comment: Thanks snow6oy for your reply. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to install "Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files". This solved the issue for me.