# Our iOS messaging app has a notification issue: certificate_revoked

Tags: ios, notifications

Our iOS messaging app has a notification problem.
We are having trouble solving this issue.

Last night, around 7 pm.
Our system got this error:
**javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_expired**

So we applied a new certificate and it had worked well.
But tonight, around 7pm
We got a new error:
**javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_revoked**

It had been working just about 1 day.
Our iOS messaging app couldn't get any notifications now.

Does anybody who know the answer?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure about the prod and sandbox mode that you are using the correct certificate?

Comment: @Mukul More, My coworker said 'yes' but I am going to doublecheck. Thanks a lot

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047100/getting-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-received-fatal-alert-handshake-fail
Check if this helps

Comment: @MukulMore Thanks :D

We finally resolved the problem.
We made a new certificate and applied it again.
It's working now. We should see what's going on n a day though.

Thanks all you guys.